# Can I create entity names at runtime? Trying to instantiate a new "Table By Hierarchy" (TBH) entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have used TPH to create a special instance of a table ie.

```
section <- introduction-section
```

There are many different section types ie conclusion

```
section <- conclusion-section
```

I need to instantiate new objects of these classes, and without TBH one would:

var myNewSection = new section();

However I am using TBH so I need to instantiate the child entity, in order to populate the discriminator correctly:

myNewSection = new I_Section ();
  db.Section.AddObject(myNewSection);

However this poses a problem in that I have to explicitly reference the TBH entity ie I_Section, and have a switch statement within the loop.

Is there a way of defining this class ie I_Section at runtime, from say a string that I could contruct from other values within the loop?

```
String strSectionCode = "I"
string strFullName = strSectionCode + "_" + "Section";

var myNewSection = new strFullname ??? () // I know this is not possible, but it shows where I am trying to get to.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Side note: Consider not using TLA like TBH, TPH... Also "create class names" reads as if you want to create new `class` which is not mentioned in the post...

Comment: Editing question regarding TLA issue. I think my create class was a mistake on my part. I want to create a new entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection you should be able to instantiate objects at runtime. Have a look at [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which provides several overloads to create instances of objects